# MongoDB concurrent read-write pairs

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, transactions, acid

How do I deal with concurrency in MongoDB?

Consider a situation where I need to perform 2 writes, both are valid on their own, but I can't accept them both.
If such writes come at the same time, latter write will not be aware of the preceding one.

Here I modeled the situation (I use mongoose):

```
const createNew = async () => {

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    const numberOfDocuments = await mongoose.model('User')
        .countDocuments()
        .session(session);

    if(numberOfDocuments > 0) return;    

    const newUser = new mongoose.model('User')();

    newUser.username = 'lol';
    newUser.email = 'lmao';

    await newUser.save(
        {
            session
        }
    );

    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();

};

createNew();
createNew();
```

The function first checks the number of documents, and it there's one already, it should stop. Though, because they execute "at the same time", both reads consider the number of documents to be 0, resulting in 2 documents getting inserted.

Two concurrent requests like this create read-read-write-write chain, is there a way to ensure it's read-write-read-write and is there's a general name for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, when transactions are used, generally reads must be under the transaction as well, not just writes. This is so that the read data doesn't end up being rolled back by the time the write is issued.

For your specific example, transactions provide ACID properties on top of operations ([atomicity and consistency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) in particular). They are not a magic solution for *mutual exclusion*. I don't think transactions will help you condition inserts on the collection size as you are trying to do.

MongoDB is not a distributed locking system. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) is a list of some software which are.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the read action was out of transaction. I fixed the code now and I did some testing again, it does not work like this too.

Though my question was not specifically about transactions. My question was how to deal with the described situation in MongoDB. The reason I had transactions in my code, is merely because it was my best attempt to approach this problem.

This is a common problem I assume, 2 valid actions happen at the same time, but when one takes place, the second becomes invalid. How can I ensure only one happens?

Comment: MongoDB is not a distributed locking system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager lists some systems that are.

Comment: So you are saying MongoDB is simply not designed for tasks like this?

Comment: There is most likely a way to implement your *use case* in MongoDB. The specific solution strategy you are attempting to proceed with, which relies on global locking, does not appear to be a good fit for MongoDB.